# Can’t add a sound effect without stopping a dice from rolling

Tags: java, android, audio

I’m programing an app the includes rolling a dice. I tried to add a sound effect of rolling dice. The sound effect works but ever since I added it the dice stopped rolling. What can I do?

```java
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

});

dice4.startAnimation(anim);

final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shake_dice);
Button roll = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_roll);

roll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sound.start();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Paste your code, not an image.

Comment: add the code *in the question*. Click "edit" link under the question and add the relevant code in there.

Comment: added a code, thank you

Comment: Play your sounds in a separate thread, not the main event thread. Look into [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool), which should help, since you can configure it to spawn threads for sounds.

Comment: use sound.prepareAsync(); after initialising sound object sound.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {

            //  now enable dice roll to click and roll 
            }

        });

then when ever dice roll is enabled it mens player is prepeared asycnhronously and the roll dice anim and start mdeia player both